# r return ngram from a vector which contains specific string

Tags: r, nlp

I want to generate `ngram` keywords from a vector, given a specific string.
For example, let's say I would need `bigram`, for each element of the vector I want to extract relevant bigrams and concatenate all the bigrams which has the keyword `ncd`.

```
have <- c('add the ncd mse to the website', 'setup new ncd staffs on t&ta for wireless. all new ncd should go to horizon', 'map out current ncd post locations on 1st, 2nd floors')

want_bigram <- c('the ncd | ncd mse', 'new ncd | ncd staffs | new ncd |ncd should', 'current ncd | ncd post')
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `tidytext` library.

```
library(tidytext)

want <- have %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
  unnest_tokens(bigrams, value, token = "ngrams", n = 2) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(bigrams, "ncd")) %>% 
  group_by(row) %>% 
  summarize(text = paste0(bigrams, collapse = " | ")) %>% 
  pull(text)
```

Output:

```
> want  
[1] "the ncd | ncd mse"                          
[2] "new ncd | ncd staffs | new ncd | ncd should"
[3] "current ncd | ncd post"
```

Comment: picking this one because of the flexibility of customizing the ngram needed and easier to include stopwords filter in the same flow

Answer (score 1):

Using `str_extract_all` you can extract strings with with one word before and after 'ncd' and combine them with `mapply`.

```
library(stringr)

mapply(function(x, y) paste(c(x, y), collapse = ' | '), 
    str_extract_all(have, '(\\w+ ncd)'), str_extract_all(have, '(ncd \\w+)'))

#[1] "the ncd | ncd mse"                          
#[2] "new ncd | new ncd | ncd staffs | ncd should"
#[3] "current ncd | ncd post"
```